2-dimensional connected Lorentz group
Consider the connected Lorentz group $SO(1,1)^{\uparrow}$. I was wondering if someone could help me about showing that $SO(1,1)^{\uparrow}\cong \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. I just need a hint.

Solve the equation defining the elements of that group.

Plus correct the claim.
